# Why my date incrementing by 2days while i'm giving only value 1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

Hello guys hope u doin well.

1. while i'm crementing date so it is incrementing by 2. while i'm incrementing by one value.
2. How to show in date field d-m-Yyy

```js
window.sum = () =>
  document.getElementById('get_my_value').value =
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('#txt1,#txt2,#txt3')
  ).map(e => parseInt(e.value) || 0)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

function increaseValueFirst() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('txt1').value = value;

}

function decreaseValueFirst() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('txt1').value = value;
}

function dateRangeSelector() {
  var days;
  var date = new Date($("#start_date").val()),
    days = parseInt($("#get_my_value").val(), 10);
  console.log("days", days);

  if (!isNaN(date.getTime())) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);

    $("#end_date").val(date.toInputFormat());
  } else {
    alert("Invalid Date");
  }
}

Date.prototype.toInputFormat = function() {
  var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
  var mm = (this.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
  var dd = this.getDate().toString();
  return yyyy + "-" + (mm[0] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + "-" + (dd[0] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]); // padding
};

$('.thisuseforaddandminus').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  //            fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field'); //there is no attribute like this on your html element
  //            type = $(this).attr('data-type');  //there is no attribute like this on your html element
  type = e.target.id == "additionofcitynights" ? "#additionofcitynights" : "#substractionofcitynights";
  //  var input = $("input[name='" + fieldName + "']"); //just getting the input by its ID
  var input = $("#get_my_value");
  var currentVal = parseInt(input.val());
  if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
    if (type == '#substractionofcitynights') {
      if (currentVal > input.attr('min')) {
        input.val(currentVal - 1).change();
      }
    } else if (type == '#additionofcitynights') {
      if (currentVal < input.attr('max')) {
        input.val(currentVal + 1).change();
      }
    }
  } else {
    input.val(0);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#start_date").datepicker();
      });
      $(function() {
        $("#end_date").datepicker();
      });
    </script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/addfields.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Modal Example</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <label>Choose Date</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start_date" name="start_date" onchange="dateRangeSelector()" value="select date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                      <label>Night</label>
                      <input type="text" name="quant[2]" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="get_my_value" onchange="dateRangeSelector()" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <label>Returning Date</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" id="end_date" name="end_date" value="Returning Date">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                      <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Serial No</th>
                            <th scope="col">Hotels</th>
                            <th scope="col">(+) Nights</th>
                            <th scope="col">(-) Nights</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td><input type="text" id="txt1" value="1" min="1" onkeyup="sum()" /></td>
                            <td>
                              <input type="button" value="+" id="additionofcitynights" value="additionofcitynights" class="thisuseforaddandminus" onclick="increaseValueFirst(); sum();">
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="button" value="-" id="substractionofcitynights" value="substractionofcitynights" class="thisuseforaddandminus" onclick="decreaseValueFirst(); sum();"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ending here displaying options -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>

  </html>
</body>

</html>
```

First i'm incrementing per days values and showing one input field.
second is total values im trying to showing in night column.
but it incrementing by 2.

1. Why date incrementing by 2.
2. How to display d-m-y.

Comment: on which line do you think is the problem?

Comment: <div class="col-sm-1">
                     <label>Night</label>
                     <input type="text" name="quant[2]" class="form-control input-number" value="0"min="0" max="100" id="get_my_value" onchange="dateRangeSelector()" readonly>
                  </div> this block it is showing value 2. while im incrementing by 1

Comment: line number 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incrementing the value in `#get_my_value` twice. First you add to it in `$('.thisuseforaddandminus').click`. After it changes the value it calls `.change()` on the input, which executes `onchange="dateRangeSelector()"`, and `dateRangeSelector()` increments the value again.

Comment: I'm not really sure quite how to fix it. I don't understand why you're doing these things in multiple places.

Comment: alright. lemme tell you. first night input field did you see over right top row. it will show all the values which is increment by other input fields. e.g if you try to make increment by one it will appear over there. if you increment by same number but different but so that top row appearing night input field will addition of both of values which is provided by different different input values.